# Property Indexer in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a context menu that I want to use in my datagrid. On each row, I'd like to have the menu show

1. If IsRunToTest == false, show the first menu item only
2. If IsRunToTest == true, show the second menu item only

Is it possible to show one of two menu items per row, based on the property IsRunToTest set? I was wondering if I need to set my IsRunToTest property as an indexer, but was not sure how to do that and make it work for each row.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestResults}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestResult}">
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Run To Selected Test" 
            Command="{Binding RunToSelectedTestAction}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsRunToTestSet, 
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, 
            ConverterParameter=Visible}" />

        <MenuItem Header="Remove Run To Selected Test" 
            Command="{Binding RemoveRunToSelectedTestAction}" 
            Visibility="{Binding IsRunToTestSet, 
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, 
            ConverterParameter=Collapsed}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>

...Defined Columns

</DataGrid>

ViewModel Properties

public ObservableCollection<TestResultsModel> TestResults
{
    get
    {
        return this.testResults;
    }

    set
    {
        this.testResults = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.TestResults);
    }
}

public TestResultsModel SelectedTestResult
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedTestResult;
    }

    set
    {
        this.selectedTestResult = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedTestResult);
    }
}

public bool IsRunToPCodeSet
{
    get
    {
        return this.SelectedTestResult.IsRunToPCodeSet;
    }

    set
    {
        this.SelectedTestResult.IsRunToPCodeSet = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsRunToPCodeSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks like it should be running fine. What are you seeing? Are both menu items being displayed? Or none at all?

Comment: Before selecting one row, I see just the first menu item. If I then select one row, it seems to work as expected. But then on a different row, I see both menu items, which I want to only see the first one, since I have not selected anything on that row.